# Using Excel, how to find child cells in a hierarchy?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Am running Excel 2010 on Windows 7 with 8 GB memory.

I have a hierarchical structure similar to figure 1 below. My structure is 1000+ rows and as deep as 15 levels.

[image: hierarchical structure]

So I am looking for a possibility to list for all values all their related children like in a picture below:

[image: resulted values]

**How to do this with excel formulas?**

Comment: I don't think you can.

Answer (score 0):

@yarkik I would use LEN(), LEFT(), TRIM(), CONCATENATE() other text functions to extract what you need from the strings.  I might help more to feed all of your data (if possible) to a pivot table that way you can drill down because the pivot table will organize the data and aggregate it.